# Can I detect when is the tab closed in VSCode? Or any other way to know when to delete a temporary file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So what I want to do is have an extension that has a treeview, where when you click an element a temporary file is created and after the user closes it, it deletes itself. Is there a way to detect it ? or is there a method on how to do it?

Comment: have you search the API page on `Close` (16 hits)